# multiprocessing different function in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two different functions in python and they both have completely independent input and output values. But they need a long time to execute and it would be good to parallelize them. How can I execute them nearly at the same time? They should have their own input and output arguments. Is that possible with the `multiprocessing` package?

I can only find examples, where they work on the same queue.

Edit:
I tried it now with `threading`

```
q = queue.Queue()
threads_list = list()
t = Thread(target=lambda fill_list, arg1: q.put(fill_list(arg1)), args=(q, list, x, y, z, xx, yy, size, stringg))
t.start()
threads_list.append(t)
for t in threads_list:
    t.join()
result = q.get()
```

but I get the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 2 positional arguments but 9 were given

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 120, in <module>
result = q.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/queue.py", line 164, in get
self.not_empty.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 295, in wait
waiter.acquire()
```

Edit: there is only this one thread in `threads_list`.

Thanks

Comment: Like this: `from threading import Thread
def func1():
    # do something
def func2():
    # do something
t1 = Thread(target=func1)
t2 = Thread(target=func2)`

Comment: With `threading` there’s the GIL issue, which `multiprocessing` doesn’t have, thought.

Comment: Some time ago I tried Raspbian python 3.7 multiprocessing (not multi-threading) and found it OK. You can create a "pool' of "processes" (not threads) and there is no GIL problem. Reference: "Python 3.8rct1 multiprocessingpackage  - Process-based parallelism":
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html. If you give us the definitions of your processes, I can trying running them for you in Rpi buster Thonny python 3.7.3. Cheers.

Comment: How many threads are in `threads_list`?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a simple example using the `multiprocessing` module, which offers process-based (as opposed to thread-based) parallelism:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
from time import sleep


def sum1(n, ret_dict):
    sleep(1.0)
    ret_dict['sum1'] = n + 1


def sum2(n, ret_dict):
    sleep(1.0)
    ret_dict['sum2'] = n + 2


def main():
    manager = Manager()
    ret_dict = manager.dict()

    input_1 = 42
    input_2 = 43

    process_1 = Process(target=sum1, args=(input_1, ret_dict))
    process_2 = Process(target=sum2, args=(input_2, ret_dict))

    process_1.start()
    process_2.start()
    process_1.join()
    process_2.join()

    print(ret_dict)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output is `{'sum1': 43, 'sum2': 45}` and it should finish in about one second (instead of about two seconds when run sequentially).

Consider also [using `multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction) if you can fit your problem into it.

Contrary to `threading`, the `multiprocessing` module "sidesteps" the [GIL (Global Interpreter Lock)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock), a *"mechanism used by the CPython interpreter to assure that only one thread executes Python bytecode at a time"*, used to ensure thread safety but severely reducing the efficiency gain of using threads. The process-based approach of `multiprocessing` uses separate processes for that and doesn't suffer from this issue.

This works well for problems that are CPU-bound and don't have *too much* communication between processes (task queues, etc, are fine).

One tangential advice, though: many times people *think* they want multi-process/multi-thread, they really have an I/O-bound scenario, and they really need async I/O, not necessarily multi-thread. For those cases, check out the [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) module.